# Drawable wrongly drawn

Tags: android

I have a video recording app where I overlay a "Start recording"/"Stop recording" button like these:

[image]

[image]

These I create using the following drawables:

Circle:

```
 <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
               android:shape="oval">

            <stroke
                android:width="3dp"
                android:color="@android:color/white"/>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />

            <padding android:bottom="10dp"
                     android:top="10dp"
                     android:right="10dp"
                     android:left="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>


    <item>
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
               android:shape="oval">
            <solid
                android:color="@color/recordingRed"/>
            <size
                android:width="40dp"
                android:height="40dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>



</layer-list>
```

Square:

```
        <padding android:bottom="10dp"
                 android:top="10dp"
                 android:right="10dp"
                 android:left="10dp" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid
            android:color="@color/recordingRed"/>
        <size
            android:width="20dp"
            android:height="20dp" />
        <corners android:topLeftRadius="3dp" android:topRightRadius="3dp"
                 android:bottomLeftRadius="3dp" android:bottomRightRadius="3dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

This works fine with, for example, the Nexus 6P, or the Nexus 5. But with a Xiaomi Redmi 3, the two icons show up okay the first time they are shown, but then when switching back and forth, they show up like so:

[image]

[image]

And then I find that I need to completely close the app and start again for them to show up properly. They only look good the first time they are shown. How can this be happening?

This is how I change the image:

```
    mRecordButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.stop_recording_border);
```

Or:

```
    mRecordButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.start_recording_border);
```

Comment: Could you try to disable hardware acceleration and reproduce it?

Comment: @g4s8 How would you go on to do that?

Comment: You can disable it on app level, activity level or for single view: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html

Comment: tried it, same result

Comment: Try to use `Button` instead of `ImageButton` and use `setBackgroundResource` instead of `setImageResource`.

Comment: Im using an `ImageView`, not an `ImageButton`